# Using SWT for multi-view application; similar to Android activity lifecycle

Tags: java, swing, swt

So my situation is simple (IMHO):

I am trying to create web-esque Java application (it's a sort of Point-Of-Sale application) that behaves much like a website, but is all in Java. Right now I have a semi-simple SWT application written in Eclipse and it displays a few options (sign in, price check, inventory check and employee timeclock). When any of these is pressed (or corresponding keyboard shortcuts are activated) a dialog box pops up prompting authentication. Assuming user is verified, I want the main application window to display a new set of functions (scan item, item lookup, etc.) seamlessly.

If this were HTML I would just make a new page, and if I were writing against the Android platform I would just create a new activity...but this is very new and I am having a very hard time finding any relevant information.

PS I'm not set on SWT if anybody thinks a different library/technology (such as Swing/AWT) is better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SWT, if you want to replace the content of a Composite, you first need to dispose the existing controls, next you create the new controls, and finally call the `layout(...)` method on the Composite:

```
// Retrieve existing composite
Composite composite = [retrieve existing composite]

// Remove exising children
for (Control child : composite.getChildren()) {
     child.dispose();
}

// Create new children
Label label = new Label(composite, SWT.NONE);

// Layout
// Maybe update the composite layout with composite.setLayout()
composite.layout(true, true);
```

Another solution is to use a `Composite` with a [StackLayout](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/UseaStackLayouttoswitchbetweenComposites.htm) if you want to display back and forth several predefined contents.

Comment: +1 - The StackLayout is probably the best idea, but be careful not to bloat your view classes with loads of stackable composites.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use Swing, AWT or SWT is entirely your choice. Personally, I prefer Swing, but you can do the same thing with SWT.

As for your predicament, you need to do a bit of studying regarding GUI's first. A Java desktop application consists of a top-level container, usually a JFrame (Window) that can contain other components, windows, dialog boxes etc.  Your best best here is to pop up a MODAL dialog box that asks the user for authentication information. If the user is authenticated, you can dynamically create buttons, text boxes etc. in your code, creating the "new" look you want.

Might I suggest you start of with some simple GUI design exercises first, before diving into a full-fledged application? Consider the Java GUI tutorials at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/ as a good starting point.

Once you have mastered basic dialogue boxes, forms and components, you'd be in a far better position to plan your GUI and will find it easier to create it just the way you want it.

Comment: Just to clarify: You are describing the way for Swing. It is quite different for SWT, especially in an RCP context. There is no JFrame in SWT. And often views are prepared by subclassing e.g. a JPanel, not possible in SWT either...